# Can't create xmlns reference to other project in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

I have a WPF project defined like this:

```
MyApp.sln
  MyAppWPF
  MyApp.Domain
```

In one of my xaml files in the MyAppWPF project I'm trying to reference a class defined in MyApp.Domain project.  I have a **project reference** in MyAppWPF to MyApp.Domain.  I am trying to create the reference like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyAppWPF.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Domain;assembly=MyApp.Domain"
    Title="Window1" Height="305" Width="485">
    <Window.Resources>
       <local:MyClass x:Key="mine" />
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

I get an error saying the assembly cannot be found, however I can create an instance of the class I want to reference in the code behind, so I know I've got it referenced correctly.

How do I do this?  Do I need a strong name, or reference the dll directly instead of using a project reference?

Comment: Hi Ted - Did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: No, but I haven't really looked at it much since I asked the question.  It was just an app to learn WPF on.

Answer (score 6):

If it helps anyone, I was able to solve my problems by simply adding `;assembly=` at the end of the namespace declaration that referred to the containing project itself. For example:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProjectNameSpace;assembly="
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if

1. the fully qualified name for MyClass is MyApp.Domain.MyClass
2. MyClass has a default public constructor (with no parameters) so that XAML can instantiate it.

Answer (score 2):

Could be of any help?
[Visual Studio 2008 (RTM) WPF Designer Could Not Load Assembly or Dependency](http://sdolha.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!4121802308C5AB4E!3591.entry)

I assume you are using Visual Studio 2008. If you are using Visual Studio 2005, this is a known issue in the XAML designer code-named "Cider", which is included in the "Visual Studio 2005 Extensions for WPF and WCF".

Answer (score 2):

You only need to put the `assembly=MyApp.Domain` if you're compiling loose XAML dynamically.

If you're just building your XAML once initially, exclude that token and just say `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Domain"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the XAML is not loose (is compiled within an assembly (DLL/EXE)
make sure that assembly has a reference to the assembly you are looking for
(right click on the project --> add reference ...).

If the XAML is loose, make sure the assembly it is looking for is copied to the same directory the exe is ran from.