# DataBinding and Incomplete Microsoft Documentation

Tags: xaml

Basically, I'm working through the Microsoft tutorial on WPF:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/opbuildpdf/framework/wpf/data/toc.pdf?branch=live

I get to page 8, and (in my opinion) Microsoft screwed up.  They don't give any C# code-behind that is necessary to run the following XAML:

```
<DockPanel
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:c="clr-namespace:SDKSample">
  <DockPanel.Resources>
    <c:MyData x:Key="myDataSource"/>
  </DockPanel.Resources>
  <DockPanel.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource myDataSource}"/>
  </DockPanel.DataContext>
  <Button Background="{Binding Path=ColorName}" Width="150" Height="30">
    I am bound to be RED!</Button>
</DockPanel>
```

I follow their description as best as possible, but all I get is this following error message.

```
The name "MyData" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:SDKSample".
```

I do what I'm supposed to do: create a c# file, using "Add New Item" and build it, but still that error code pops up again.  To save people from having to look up the documentation, here's what they ask for:

> Consider the following example, in which the binding source object is
>   a class named MyData that is defined in the SDKSample namespace. For
>   demonstration purposes, MyData class has a string property named
>   ColorName, of which the value is set to "Red". Thus, this example
>   generates a button with a red background.

I've looked in the various SDK's for this example, hoping I'd find the mysterious C# file somewhere, but alas I can't find it.  It seems like Microsoft forgot a link.  You know, even if it is somewhere in an SDK, it is extremely hard to find.  As someone in a learning-mode, I'd hope that all the gritty details would be provided in the documentation, not just the quote from above, which doesn't go into any details as to where to put the C# file, how you are supposed to build so it will properly get registered as existing.

So, if anyone can find a nice description as to how to get the XAML code to work, by creating a C# class named "MyData" in a "SDKSamples" namespace, I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

the xaml works when you add the following:

```
namespace SDKSample
{
    public class MyData
    {
        public Brush ColorName { get; set; } = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong?  I started a new Project, opened up the MainWindow.XAML.cs file, and then put your code right below the auto-generated code that is there after you create a new project.  The XAML stuff I just cut and pasted.  Still I get this one error:` "The name "MyData" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:SDKSample".`

Comment: did you try to build? run the program?

Comment: Hi Milan.  TY for the help.  Yes, I tried to build and run it.  It doesn't even go to the build stage.  I also tried a few things from this page:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216749/cant-create-xmlns-reference-to-other-project-in-xaml?rq=1 but it still has same error.  That did tell me something though.  It's as if the C# class I made doesn't exist at all to the XAML code.  I can change the xmlns:c="clr-namespace:SDKSample"> line to xmlns:c="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" and get the same error.

Comment: clean and rebuild the solution? ;/ what does "It doesn't even go to the build stage" mean? after you clean and rebuild the solution, what output do you see in the build output? does it say something failed to build?

Comment: After "Clean Solution" and then "Build Solution" it just says "Build Failed" at the lower left of the screen.  It has the same error message as before, "MyData" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:SDKSample".

Comment: did you put the dockpanel inside the auto-generated xaml? does your xaml start with the mainwindow?

Comment: I only cut and pasted the XAML from my original post.  The XAML doesn't start, and only has a blue squiggly under <c:MyData.  When I go to the design page, it says, "The Design view cannot display correctly because some custom elements have not yet been built."

Comment: When you create a new wpf app, you get mainwindow.xaml and inside it you have a window, and inside that window there is a grid. Now, put that dockpanel inside that grid. Or is this how you do it already?

Comment: Thanks Milan, you got the old neurons firing and synapses communicating.  After starting a new project, and then cutting and pasting in the relevant code, the following worked:

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="StackExchangeQuestion.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackExchangeQuestion"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:SDKSample"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel >
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <c:MyData x:Key="myDataSource"/>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
    <DockPanel.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource myDataSource}"/>
    </DockPanel.DataContext>
    <Button Background="{Binding Path=ColorName}" Width="150" Height="30">
        I am bound to be RED!</Button>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I'd like to add that Microsoft assumes that you have all the stuff between `<Window x:Class and Width="525">` already there.  It's kind of sloppy work to just leave out that massive detail in their documentation.  Thanks to Milan for getting me to look at what should go inside the `<Window>...</Window>` part of the code.

Also, in the interest of completeness, the C# code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace StackExchangeQuestion
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

namespace SDKSample
{
    public class MyData
    {
        public Brush ColorName { get; set; } = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```